# Compare two strings and count how many times two words match

Tags: php, explode

I have two strings such as:

```
$string1 = 'Hi how are you today';
$string2 = 'how' AND 'today';
```

$string1 could be anything as it gets it's content through a loop.

I want to be able to count how many times the two words in $string2 appear in $string1.  Both words have to exist, in any order.

This is what I have so far.  But it only checks if "text" exists.  How can I change it to check if "text" and "text2" exist in any order.

```
$sitesToCheck = array("http://mysitecom.com", "http://mysitetwocom.com"));

foreach ($sitesToCheck as $site) {
    $html = file_get_html($site);
    foreach ( $html->find('.table tr td.span8') as $element ) {
        $list .=  $element->plaintext;
        $item_count = count(explode('text', $list));
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. 
You can use PHP's [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$string1 = 'Hi how are you today';
$string2 = 'how today';
$arr1 = explode(" ",$string1 );
$arr2 = explode(" ",$string2 );
$result = array_intersect($arr1 , $arr2 ); //matched elements
$num = count($result); //number of matches
```